# Does pytorch 2.0 exploit parallelism in a computational graph during inference?

Tags: pytorch

I have a pytorch model, the forward pass looks roughly like the following

```py
def forward(x):
    lidar_features = self.lidar_encoder(x['pointcloud'])
    camera_features = self.camera_encoder(x['images'])
    combined_features = torch.stack((lidar_features, camera_features))
    output = self.prediction_head(combined_features)
    return output
```

During inference, is pytorch 2.0 smart enough to know that the lidar encoder and camera encoder can be run at the same time on the GPU, but then a sync needs to be inserted before the `torch.stack`? And does it have the capability to do this out of the box?